# Move Oracle Local Database

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So for school i need to make a database(local) with some test data in it. Now i'm currently making this on my main desktop PC (for efficiency reasons) 
However i need to move the database and all of its test data to another PC (my laptop that i take to school with me)

I've searched on google in all ways i possibly could, but have yet to find how to export the database + test data in a way that i can import/open it on my laptop with Oracle SQL Developer (same tool i use on my main PC).

I was wondering how/where Oracle stores this local database that i just spent quite a while on making and how to move it to my USB/Laptop.

I use Oracle XE to make the local (connection is to 127.0.0.1) work.
Cheers,
Icy

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't have a local database, it's just a client. Are you sure you have a database on your PC? You have the Oracle Server software installed, not just client software? And your connection string is to localhost or your PC's name/IP address?

Comment: Yes, I installed a software (Oracle aswell) called XE , which allowed me to use it locally, as for the the connection is 127.0.0.1 (aka locally)

Comment: OK, so you need to install the same software on your laptop to start with, then look at export/import options. Have you looked at [datapump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_dp.htm), or are you only interested in SQL Developer solutions?

Comment: As for the solution, it doesn't really matter, but the database has to be build in SQL Developer due to school guides etc work with this program. I got exactly the same software on my laptop, i'll look into the datapump you linked

Comment: Again, SQL Developer is the client. You can use Toad, SQL\*Plus, or anything else to access the data in your database. If your schools requires you to use that client for your DDL and DML scripts/statements that's fine, but that has nothing to do with how you move your data. You can use SQL Developer's export wizard though - [this is old](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm) but probably close enough. Or [this](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/)

Comment: The link you posted seems to output a massive SQL script, from what i saw all the correct test data AND database links etc. are in there. I'm currently waiting for it to finish installing the XE on my laptop, but i'm pretty sure i can make the database from the file i just created via the link. Because i just need a SQL file, this is how i gotten the database from my school and how the generator spit out test data, so i can just run the massive SQL script and let it implement the data. This should be it , thanks :) i'll mark as answer if its done and working :)

Answer (score 0):

Going to `Tools > Database Export` and selecting the right `connection` created a `SQL script` that i could move and run on my laptop to copy the entire database and all its data to my Laptop.